# WCF protocols that supports Callback Service

Tags: .net, wcf

I want to implement wcf duplex communication with callback service with multiple wcf protocols. can anyone suggest me which protocols supports duplex callback services in wcf service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following WCF bindings support duplex:

- [WSDualHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NetHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nethttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NetTcpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NetNamedPipeBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NetPeerTcpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netpeertcpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NetTcpContextBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpcontextbinding(v=vs.110).aspx)